# Get resourses of default tab bar icons in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I get the resourses of default tab bar icons in iOS 7 ?

Such that, I want to use an existing Apple image (icon) with my own title in a TabBarItem

Comment: Ok. But, is there any way to do that in iOS 6 ?

Comment: [iOS 7 - UIKit](https://github.com/youknowone/UI7Kit)

Answer (score 0):

hello you can try it this way,

```
-(void)loadTabBarView
{
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.navViewController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navViewController.navigationBar.hidden=TRUE;
self.navViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Home";
[self.navViewController.tabBarItem initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:1];

self.vcMenuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navMenuViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vcMenuViewController];
self.navMenuViewController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navMenuViewController.navigationBar.hidden=TRUE;
self.navMenuViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Menu";
[self.navMenuViewController.tabBarItem initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemDownloads tag:2];

NSArray *arrayWithController = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.navViewController,self.navMenuViewController,nil];// self.navNewsTab, nil];

self.tabBar=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
self.tabBar.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[self.tabBar setViewControllers:arrayWithController];
}
```

Comment: I have tried that in coding and in storyboard, but it did not work for me.

Comment: strange coz i've created a demo and it worked fine for me but that is not of storyboard but a simple view based xib project

Comment: I want to add a tabBarItem that has the "Contact" Image, that apple provides, with a custom title.

Comment: try this demo it is not with storyboard but it satiesfied your needs

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1l73k2ifjmqzeb/SimpleTabDemo.zip

Comment: if not worked for you then send me your sample code and i'll try and make edit and let you know if its done